# Pass dynamically changing values between screens in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've searched in the online documentation but I didn't find any useful result. Since I'm quite new to Flutter, is there any possible way to pass a value from a screen to another updating also its value? I mean, on one screen it is updating every second (e.g. a counter), and I would like to see the same update when passing to the next screen.
I've tried to pass the value as an argument of the class that defines the next screen, but it is passing only the last recordered value and the update is not happening.

The following is the first screen, and the variable to pass is CO2Data_2 (global)

```
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:app_co2/Visual_test.dart';
import 'package:app_co2/visual.dart';
import 'package:app_co2/exportCSV.dart';
import 'package:app_co2/dataChart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

/* class time {
  time(this.time_value);

  Uint8 time_value;
}
 */
int time = 0;
int CO2Data_000 = 0;
int CO2Data_00 = 0;
int CO2Data_0 = 0;
int CO2Data_1 = 0;
int CO2Data_2 = 0;
double C02_Data_2_double = 0.0;

List<List<String>> dataForCSV = [
  ['Time', 'CO2 Value']
];

List<ChartData> dataForPlot = [];
ChartData CO2_for_plot = ChartData(0, 0);

double screen_width = 1.0;
double screen_height = 1.0;

//List<int> CO2_array = [];
//final List<int> charCodes = const [97, 98, 99, 100];
late List<LiveData> chartData;
late ChartSeriesController _chartSeriesController;

class LiveData {
  LiveData(this.time, this.speed);
  final int time;
  final int speed;
}

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = '';
//List<int> value = [];

class DataVisualization extends StatelessWidget {
  final BluetoothDevice device;
  final BluetoothService service;
  final BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic;

  const DataVisualization(
      {Key? key,
      required this.device,
      required this.service,
      required this.characteristic})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screen_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    screen_height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: buildAppBar(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: [
                  StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
                      stream: characteristic.value,
                      initialData: characteristic.lastValue,
                      builder: (c, snapshot) {
                        final value = snapshot.data;

                        //Data collection
                        CO2Data_000 = CO2Data_00;
                        CO2Data_00 = CO2Data_0;
                        CO2Data_0 = CO2Data_1;
                        CO2Data_1 = CO2Data_2;
                        CO2Data_2 = returnInteger(value as List<int>);

                        //Chart data setup
                        C02_Data_2_double = CO2Data_2.toDouble();
                        time = time + 1;
                        CO2_for_plot = ChartData(time, C02_Data_2_double);
                        dataForPlot.add(CO2_for_plot);

                        //Time saving and display
                        now = DateTime.now();
                        formattedDate =
                            DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm:ss').format(now);

                        //CSV setup
                        dataForCSV.addAll([
                          [formattedDate, CO2Data_2.toString()]
                        ]);

                        /* dataForPlot.addAll([
                          [time, CO2Data_2 as double]
                        ]); */

                        String csv =
                            const ListToCsvConverter().convert(dataForCSV);

                        //Visual return
                        return Container(
                            //child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            //  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                            height: 10,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          ),
                          //Text(' '),

                          Text('Measured CO2 value',
                              style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              )),

                          Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(CO2Data_2.toString(),
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 26, 201, 19)),
                                      fontSize: 70,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    )),
                                Text(' ppm',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 26, 201, 19)),
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    ))
                              ]),

                          Text(formattedDate.toString(),
                              style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              )),

                          Container(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                            height: 10,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          ),

                          Text(''),

                          Text('Previous values',
                              style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                fontSize: 25,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              )),

                          Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(CO2Data_1.toString(),
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                      fontSize: 50,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    )),
                                Text(' ppm',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    ))
                              ]),

                          Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(CO2Data_0.toString(),
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color:
                                              //Color.fromARGB(255, 6, 60, 104)),
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 78, 131)),
                                      fontSize: 50,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    )),
                                Text(' ppm',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 78, 131)),
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    ))
                              ]),

                          Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(CO2Data_00.toString(),
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color:
                                              //Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 78, 131)),
                                              Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 28, 105, 168)),
                                      fontSize: 50,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    )),
                                Text(' ppm',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color.fromARGB(
                                              255, 28, 105, 168)),
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    ))
                              ]),

                          Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(CO2Data_000.toString(),
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: //Color.fromARGB(255, 28, 105, 168)
                                              Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 67, 152, 221)),
                                      fontSize: 50,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    )),
                                Text(' ppm',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color.fromARGB(
                                              255, 67, 152, 221)),
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    ))
                              ]),

                          Text(''),

                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              MaterialButton(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(40))),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: screen_height / 100,
                                      horizontal: screen_width / 8),
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 56, 211),
                                  minWidth:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                                  disabledColor:
                                      Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 167, 101),
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => ExportCSV(
                                                dataForCSV: dataForCSV,
                                                date: formattedDate,
                                              ))),
                                  child: Text(
                                    '  EXPORT CSV  ',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              Container(
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 15),
                              MaterialButton(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(40))),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: screen_height / 100,
                                      horizontal: screen_width / 40),
                                  color: Color(0xFFFBC02D),
                                  minWidth:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                                  disabledColor:
                                      Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 167, 101),
                                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => DataChart(
                                                dataForPlot: dataForPlot,
                                              ))),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'DATA CHART VISUALIZATION',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            ],
                          ),
                          MaterialButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: screen_height / 100,
                                  horizontal: screen_width / 8),
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 211,
                                  9), //245, 23, 81, 123, 81 //255, 211, 117, 9
                              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                              disabledColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 167, 101),
                              onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                        AlertDialog(
                                      elevation: 10,
                                      title: Text('ATTENTION',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                    255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                            fontSize: 25,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                          )),
                                      content: Text(
                                          'Are you sure you want to delete CSV data?',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                    255, 1, 38, 68)),
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          )),
                                      actions: <Widget>[
                                        TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () =>
                                              Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                                          child: const Text('Cancel'),
                                        ),
                                        TextButton(
                                          onPressed: () => clearData(dataForCSV,
                                              dataForPlot, context, time),
                                          child: const Text('OK'),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                              child: Text(
                                '  CLEAR CSV DATA  ',
                                style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                ),
                              )),

                          //Text(''),
                        ]));
                      })
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        )));
  }

  AppBar buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68),
      title: Text("Data visualization",
          style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            fontSize: 23,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          )),
    );
  }
}

int returnInteger(List<int> data) {
  int converted = 0;
  for (var i = 0, length = 4; i < length; i++) {
    converted += data[i] * (pow(256, i) as int);
  }
  return converted;
}

void clearData(
    List<List<String>> data1, List<ChartData> data2, context, int time) {
  data1.clear();
  data1 = [
    ['Time', 'CO2 Value']
  ];
  data2.clear();
  time = 0;
  Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel');
}
```

The second screen is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'package:app_co2/DataVisualization.dart';
import 'package:app_co2/exportCSV.dart';

class DataChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ChartData> dataForPlot;

  const DataChart({Key? key, required this.dataForPlot}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: buildAppBar(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
            child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                  //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                Text('Measured CO2 value',
                    style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                      textStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68)),
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    )),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(CO2Data_2.toString(),
                          style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 26, 201, 19)),
                            fontSize: 70,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          )),
                      Text(' ppm',
                          style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 26, 201, 19)),
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          ))
                    ]),
                Container(
                  child: SfCartesianChart(series: <ChartSeries>[
                    // Renders line chart
                    LineSeries<ChartData, int>(
                        dataSource: dataForPlot,
                        xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
                        yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y)
                  ]),
                ),
                Text(''),
                MaterialButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: screen_height / 100,
                        horizontal: screen_width / 8),
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 56, 211),
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
                    disabledColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 194, 167, 101),
                    onPressed: () =>
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ExportCSV(
                                  dataForCSV: dataForCSV,
                                  date: formattedDate,
                                ))),
                    child: Text(
                      '  EXPORT CSV  ',
                      style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    )),
                Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 15),
              ])),
        )));
  }

  AppBar buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 38, 68),
      title: Text("Data chart",
          style: GoogleFonts.catamaran(
            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            fontSize: 23,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          )),
    );
  }
}

class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y);
  final int x;
  final double y;
}
```

I would like CO2Data_2 in this second screen to update as it updates continuously in the first screen.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: @AhmadRaza just did it

Answer (score 0):

For managing a shared state across your app you may want to look into a state management library such as Provider, Riverpod, or Bloc. Provider is the one used in the [example from Flutter.](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) You can place your shared state in a provider and then access and edit it from other locations in your app.